# Simpler solution against CSRF?

Tags: browser, web, security, csrf

I've been thinking about [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF), and couldn't answer myself why web browser developers don't use a simpler solution.

Instead of disallowing cross domain scripts, why can't they allow any access to any site, but with an empty cookie jar? (or rather, a cookie jar that contains only the cookies of the current domain)

Same thing about any tag (img, script, etc.)

If any access is with no cookies, what CSRF can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding a cookie jar w/ only the cookies of the current domain: the cookies of the current domain may contain session information for example.  This information could then be sent over the wire and result in session hijacking (for example).

Even if the scripts did not have cookie information, there could be other sensitive information on a website, perhaps visible through the DOM.  This information could then be uploaded cross domain.

As an side, I don't think the same origin policy actually does anything to stop malicious hackers.  As you said img's and scripts can make requests out.  I can run a server that returns a 404, but keeps a log of the GET requests (for example: maliciouswebsitehere.com/fake404.html?bankaccountnumber=34398439843983&otherinformation=blah)

Comment: "there could be other sensitive information on a website"... how can it be? if there's any information on a site, that information won't be private... it would be same information you get if anyone is making the request..
As for your Fake404.html example, I didn't understand you. How can this be used for CSRF? or any malicious activity?

Comment: You are assuming all the sensitive information about the current page is in the cookies and if the cookies are inaccessible when making cross domain requests, then there is no problem right?  I do not think this is true.  Here's a an example: imagine logging in as an admin to an intranet with say, employee email/SSN/whatever.  The page also has engadget.com news on it out of convenience for the admin.  If someone plants an XSS attack on the engadget, the admin's page (with the sensitive info) can be scraped and sent cross domain - no cookies involved